# $\int_{O}\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2}=\int_{O}(\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x\partial y})^2$

Tags: calculus

Moreover, $w=w(x,y)$ and $O=(0,1)\times(0,1)$, and $w=0$ on the boundary $\partial O$ of the domain $O$.

I understand integration by parts should be used, and it's not problem to come to the expression on the right side this way, but I don't see how remaining terms produced by integration by parts get eliminated.

What I got by integration by parts is as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
& & \int_{O}\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2} \\
& = & \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}\cdot\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \\
& = & \int_{0}^{1}\Big[\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}\cdot\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\Big]_{y=0}^{y=1}\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial^3 w}{\partial x^2\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \\
& = & \int_{0}^{1}\Big[\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}\cdot\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\Big]_{y=0}^{y=1}\mathrm{d}x-\int_{0}^{1}\Big[\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\Big]_{x=0}^{x=1}\mathrm{d}y+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}(\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x\partial y})^2\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \\
\end{eqnarray}

Thus, if above is correct, the problem is how to get rid of the first two terms.

Comment: What terms remain in your calculation? I would guess that they can be handled by using the boundary condition of $u$. Btw: Is $u \in C^2(O) \cap C(\bar O)$ or belongs $u$ to some Sobolev space?

Comment: Yes, $w\in H^2(O)\cap H_0^1(O)$.

Comment: By $H^1(O)$, I meant on Sobolev space $\{w(x,y)\in L_{2}(O):\frac{\partial w}{\partial x}\in L_{2}(O)\wedge\frac{\partial w}{\partial y}\in L_{2}(O)\}$, while $H_{0}^{1}(O)$ is same thing, but where $w(x,y)=0$ on the boundary $\partial O$. Also, $H^{2}(O)$ is alike as $H^{1}(O)$, but where all second partial derivatives are also Lebesgue integrable on $O$ too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we see that your equation holds if $w \in C^\infty(\bar O)$ and $w = 0$ on $\partial O$, since the boundary terms vanish in this case (note that $w = 0$ on $\partial O$ implies $\partial w / \partial x = 0$ is zero on the boundaries with $y = \pm 1$ and the other way round).

Now, let $w \in H^2(0) \cap H_0^1(O)$ be given. Then, there is a sequence $w_k \in C^\infty(\bar O)$, $w_k = 0$ on $\partial O$, such that $w_k \to w$ in $H^2(O)$. Since the mapping
$$
v \mapsto \int_O \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y^2} - \Big(\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x \partial y}\Big)^2\, dx
$$
is continuous w.r.t. $v \in H^2(O)$, we obtain
$$
0 = \int_O \frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial y^2} - \Big(\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial x \partial y}\Big)^2\, dx
$$

This is a usual technique when working with Sobolev spaces: Proof the result for smooth functions and then use a density argument.

Comment: Got it, thanks!